# i wanna achieve is filter all the orders to get all the products sold by each seller

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  orderDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  products: { type: Array, default: [] }
});
const Order = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
module.exports = Order;

"products" : [
      {
        _id: "5f0289147b9b980f40d4f2e6",
        product: ObjectId("5f02879f7160ae0c2c203cdf"),
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        _id: "5f0289177b9b980f40d4f2e7",
        product: ObjectId("5f02879f7160ae0c2c203fgg"),
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
"product" : {
  _id: "5f02879f7160ae0c2c203cdf",
  name: "Some Car",
  category: "5f027c5ca1b94820b856c508",
  seller: "5f0276cf965f8c29e019a7f1" //seller can be different for each product
}
```

I wanna achieve is filter all the orders to get all the products sold by each seller. like if I'm a seller and I'm logged in, I wanna get all the products sold by me in the Order collection

Comment: does [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) help?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a shared id across the tables so that you can
`const soldProducts = products.filter(product => product.id === id)`
soldProducts would then be a new array of products that have a matching id with your user ID. (if this is how your db is constructed). I think this would be the easiest way.